# Skip code execution if input field is not found

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to test a case where I have random additional login screen which appears into the application.

```
WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 4);
WebElement inputBox = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("username.input")));
    
String textInsideInputBox = inputBox.getAttribute("value");
    
if(!textInsideInputBox.isEmpty())
{
    // Insert Search text for Shipping License Plate
    insertInputField(driver, "username.input", "warehouse");
    
    // Insert Search text for Serial Number
    insertInputField(driver, "password.input", "password");
    
    // Click Authorize button
    clickButton(driver, "authorization.authorize.button", "Authorize");
}
```

I use this code to detect the login screen which popups. But when the logion window is not should I get of course `waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: username.input`. Is it possible silently to skip this code execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use function like this:

```
public boolean waitForElementToBeVisible(By element) {
    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));
        return true;
    }catch (Throwable t){
        return false;
    }
}
```

With it you can achieve what you asked for like this:

```
if(waitForElementToBeVisible(By.id("username.input"))){
    WebElement inputBox = driver.findElement(By.id("username.input"));

    String textInsideInputBox = inputBox.getAttribute("value");
    
    if(!textInsideInputBox.isEmpty())
    {
        // Insert Search text for Shipping License Plate
        insertInputField(driver, "username.input", "datex.local\\fp_warehouse");
    
        // Insert Search text for Serial Number
       insertInputField(driver, "password.input", "PortalPortal@5655!");
    
        // Click Authorize button
        clickButton(driver, "authorization.authorize.button", "Authorize");
    } 
}
```